# SHOW COLUMNS from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables, describe

I am trying to get the column names from 2 tables.

I tried a query like: `(SHOW COLUMNS FROM users) UNION (SHOW COLUMNS FROM posts)` but that does not work & returns a syntax error. I tried the same query using `DESCRIBE` but that did not work either. **How can I get all the column names from multiple tables in a single query?**  Is it possible?

Comment: If it is of any interest to anyone, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs for version 5.0 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

```
"SHOW COLUMNS displays information about the columns in a given table"
```

So you can't really use it on multiple tables.  However if you have `information_schema` database then you could use it like follows:

```
select column_name 
from `information_schema`.`columns` 
where `table_schema` = 'mydb' and `table_name` in ('users', 'posts');
```

Here you'd have to replace the `mydb` with your database name, or just use `DATABASE()`.

Comment: @Namphibian, Whoops! :)

Comment: No worries. All about the spirit of things.

Answer (score 5):

Yes use the information_Schema views.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE Table_Name=? OR Table_name=?;
```

Use them as they are a standards way of querying database metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If you also would like to get the name of the table column is from select `table_name` too

```
SELECT column_name, table_name 
FROM `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE `table_schema` = DATABASE() AND `table_name` in ('table1', 'table2');
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming that you actually want to list all columns of the tables involved in a join.*

---

There is a neat trick to view the ***qualified*** table and column names in a select statement. First [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) the select query, then look at the result of [`SHOW WARNINGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

The result will look something like this:

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Note | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `testdb`.`users`.`id` AS `id`,`testdb`.`users`.`name` AS `name`,`testdb`.`posts`.`id` AS `id`,`testdb`.`posts`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`testdb`.`posts`.`name` AS `name` from `testdb`.`users` join `testdb`.`posts` where (`testdb`.`users`.`id` = `testdb`.`posts`.`user_id`) |

The resulting query contains fully qualified name of all columns inside the select clause instead of `*`.