# How to get the Names of the columns in MYSQL

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I want to get the column names of a table.The following code doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't show any columns names either.

Can anyone see what mistake I'm making please?

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '!!mytablename!!'";
$real_q = mysql_query($q);
foreach ($r = mysql_fetch_row($real_q) as $taxokey => $taxovalue ) {
    if ($taxokey != 'name') {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php print($taxokey);?>"><?php print($taxovalue);?></option>
    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please see the answer here to select columns of a MySQL table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846387/mysql-show-columns-from-multiple-tables/17846511#17846511

Comment: Thanks for editing, I edited again because of typo.

Comment: Anyway, I think the reason I cannot see the result is because of 'mysql_fetch_row' because it shows only one column name. Is there way to show all column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Query with

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='mytablename'"
```

Comment: ... `AND TABLE_SCHEMA='databasename';` / `AND TABLE_SCHEMA=database();`

Comment: I think the reason I cannot see the result is because of 'mysql_fetch_row' because it shows only one column name. Is there way to show all column names?

Comment: @user2499003: instead of `foreach ($r = mysql_fetch_row($real_q) as $taxokey => $taxovalue `, use `while($r = mysql_fetch_row($real_q))`, every column is a new row here, so multiple rows have to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can just do

```
  $q = "desc mytable;";
```

That will give you column names and datatype information both.

What is !!mytablename!!?  Is that supposed to be your table name or an attempt to put the value from a variable in the string?  Because if its the latter, that's your problem.